# Antitrust in Halacha

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, contemporary-halacha, business

In Halacha, is there a notion of antitrust in the sense of there being a problem with a business starting up in an area to compete against another business and buying up that business? [Antitrust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competition_law) in secular law exists to protect small businesses and consumers from larger  businesses from buying up the rest of the market. Does a parallel  exist in Jewish law?

Comment: Look into the somewhat related (although certainly not identical) concept of Hasagat Gevul

Comment: @JoelK Also hafkaas she'arim.

Comment: @meir That's a form of regulation for cases where monopoly/market power exists, right?

Comment: @AKA I suppose so, although the issue isn't the monopoly itself but the unfair pricing. But someone who knows Choshen Mishpat better than I do would have to address the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Talmud sets limits on competition: One town can prevent another town from competing with them in the same business, but it cannot if that town pays it taxes (and tariffs).  But, within the same town, competition is permitted. [Bava Batra 21b]